# wierd bash behavior when reading string with wildcard

Tags: string, bash, wildcard

I'm working on centOS 7 with bash 4.2, and I witness strange behavior.
Here is what I try to do:

I have a script that copies a template and adds index name to the new file, like so:

original folder:

- file1
- file2

to:

- file1
- file2
- index.file1
- index.file2

Additionaly, the script creates a tmp file that stores the index name.
What I want to do is to eventually load and send (separately) via curl all the files with the index name at the start of their name.

Where the problem starts? When the index has wildcard in it.
lets say the index name is INDEX*.
The new files are:

- file1
- file2
- INDEX*.file1
- INDEX*.file2
- tmp (cat tmp = "INDEX*")

The tmp file contains only INDEX*, as I see if I run cat on it.

If I try to load the contents to a variable in bash, like this:

```
index_name=$(<tmp)
echo index name: $index_name
```

And the result is a string that contains all the files with INDEX in them, like so:

```
index name: INDEX*.file1 INDEX*.file2
```

That was wierd because this is not that tmp has in it, but I tried to at least turn this string into an array and just have the list of files I need anyway.
I tried it like so:

```
IFS=' ' read -a index_array <<< "$index_name"
```

It turn the string into an array with 1 element = the full string...

I guess that the wildcard in the index name is the thing causing the issue, so does anyone know any work around?

I thought mabye to save the index name in tmp without the wildcard and then just load all the files that has INDEX in their name, but this is risky - mainly because I can't guarentee that the wildcard will allways be at INDEX end.

So what can I do?

Is there a way to make bash understand that in this case "*" should be treated as a string and not as wildcard?

If not, Is there a way to make bash seperate the string into sepreated strings?

Any help will be appreciated...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes): If you quote the arguments to `echo` the globs will not be expanded.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but does it echo what is accualy saved (when I use quotes) in the variable or does it only change the "echo" command?

Comment: It changes how the shell interprets the input before even passing it to the `echo` command. Please follow the link.